# How to get response in Android Webview using secured HTTPS connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new in android and i get stuck in some problems. i build a log-in page for my app and i want to get access to a HTTPS website and now i m using onReceivedHttpAuthRequest function, when i input the correct credential,its ok to access to the website. Now the problem is if i input wrong credential, i will get a blank page and didn't show any content or error message. So i wonder if there is a way that when i input the credential then app can check them and return some response so i can direct the page back to log-in page when input incorrect credential. 
Cheers.

The following is part of my code

[image]

Comment: Ty bro, i cant add that image directly, now it makes more sense:)

Comment: why using image if you can copy paste your code